Cannot copy and paste into a layer
I am having a very frustrating problem in ArcMap. (This is all within the one enterprise geodatabase.)
I am trying to copy and paste a feature from one layer to another (similar layers).
I have been following the Esri guide on how to and found the same answer on here.

https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/copy-features-between-layers/
Copying features from one layer into different layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?

The issue is that it says it will past into the new layer, after pasting it is in the new layer while selected.
BUT when I clear selection the copied feature returns to the layer of the original feature.
I do not know what I am doing wrong. It is probably something simple. I have restarted my computer 3x so far.

Are you doing this in an edit session? Are both feature classes SDE (enterprise database)? Do you have write access to the 'paste' feature class or are you only a 'viewer' of that feature class? Does the paste to layer have a definition query that would exclude the pasted feature? (don't laugh, I've fallen into that trap and ended up with 30 invisible features). Have you tried the Copy Features tool https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000 ?

@MichaelStimson, I am in an edit session. Both layers are in the same SDE. How do I check if I have write access to a layer? (there have been many times where I have not been given appropriate permissions, or had them removed for no reason). How do i see the definition query? the new feature is definitely created, just in the original layer, it is only in the desired layer while highlighted after pasting. then it converts to the copied layer

Can you please edit your question to include a link to the related posts on GIS.SE and Esri so we're not making the same suggestions you've already got. The definition query is on the layer, right click on the layer in ArcMap, select properties and then the Definition Query tab.

@MichaelStimson, the same thing happens when I try to copy and paste from the opposite layers (i.e. instead of L1 to L2, going from L2 to L1). I have been following this guide https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/copying-and-pasting-features.htm#:~:text=Note%3A 1 Click the Edit tool on the,pasted feature. ... 6 Click OK . 

Can you try to create a feature in your 'to' layer using Create Features then in the Spatial Adjustment toolbar set up attibute transfer, auto match and include the geometry as well, then using attribute transfer click on the source feature and the destination feature. If that doesn't work the point of failure would be a clue to what is potentially going wrong. You could also try ending your edit session, select the source feature and use Copy Features, if that works that would indicate there may be a problem in your delta tables. Does your database get compressed and validated regularly?

Could it be that both layers have the same data source (feature class), but with different query definitions?  In this case, you would be copying/pasting to the same feature class (even though a different layer), but the definition queries would make sure that the copied feature will only appear in the layer from which it was copied.  To get around this, you would need to know what the definition queries on the layers are, and you would need to edit the pasted feature to match the definition query of the destination layer.

@SonofaBeach that is pretty likely as one layer (the one I am transferring to) is the "not in use" version. I have been shown how to do this previously and it worked. It just seems to not work when I have nobody I can ask

So you need to edit your question to include the definition queries of both layers.  (As explained in an earlier comment.)  This will make it easier (possible) to determine how to make the copied feature match the definition query.

I've made the same mistake previously of pasting into a layer and having the definition query hide the feature. I strongly suggest that you answer your own question for future users who make the same mistake as you and I.

@MichaelStimson, Thank you for your help. One step ahead of you. I have added a bottom section of Edit: Solved with the solution

You should post your solution as an answer, not as part of the question (as suggested by MichaelStimson).   Oh well, I've just posted the answer now instead.  If it is correct, then mark it as correct (click the tick/check mark next to it).  That way other people will know that this question is no longer requiring an answer.

That behaviour makes it seem to me that both layers have the same data source (ie, the same feature class), but with different query definitions.  In this case, you would be copying/pasting to the same feature class (even though a different layer), but the definition queries would make sure that the copied feature will only appear in the layer from which it was copied.
To get around this, you would need to know what the definition queries on the layers are, and you would need to edit the pasted feature to match the definition query of the destination layer.  You can see the definition query in the layer's Properties window.
Eg, if the two layers had the following definition queries:
Source Layer:  NOTINUSE = 'N'
Destination Layer:  NOTINUSE = 'Y'
Then in the layer's attributes table you would need to change the value of NOTINUSE from N to Y for a feature to cause it to disappear from the source layer and appear in the destination layer.  (Or use the Attributes pane, instead of the Attributes table.)
It's worth noting that this is a common problem.  Not just with copying features, but I often have the issue when creating new features and with appending features ('Append' tool).  It still catches me off-guard and scratching my head sometimes, even after experiencing the issue many times.  The feature(s) are created, but then disappear from both the map and the attributes table.  Or the 'Append' tool finishes running successfully, but the features never appear on the map or in the attributes table.  It can be very confusing until you remember that the layer has a definition query that is excluding them.
